# Почему pdo query select возвращает null?

Tags: php, pdo

Есть класс подключения к базе данных:

```
class Mydb
{
    protected $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            exit($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

И два класса-наследника: для добавления данных в базу

```
class AddData extends Mydb
{
    public function addInfo($name, $tel, $email)
    {
        $this->db->exec("INSERT INTO users (name, tel, email) VALUES ('$name', '$tel', '$email'");
    }
}
```

и для получения из базы

```
class GetData extends Mydb
{
    public function getInfo()
    {
        $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    }
}
```

Объект класса AddData со своей функцией справляется отлично:

```
$add = new AddData();
$add->addInfo('Vasya', '(495) 123-45-67', 'vas@ya.ru');
```

А вот объект класса GetData почему-то возвращает NULL:

```
$get = new GetData();
$res = $get->getInfo();
var_dump($res); //NULL
```

Причём если $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users"); поместить в конструктор родительского класса, то всё работает. А через класс-наследник - нет.

В чём здесь проблема и как её решить?

Comment: return  забыл в getInfo()

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов да, с return заработало, спасибо!

Comment: `$add->addInfo('Vasya', '(495) 123-45-67', 'vas@ya.ru\'), (\'Запасной аккаунт\', \'\',\'');`

Answer (score 2):

Я не знаю, где выучились писать классы, то что написано в вопросе - это страшнее атомной войны.

"класс" Mydb выкинуть на помойку, остальные объединить в один.

```
class User
{
    public function __construct($pdo) {
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }
    public function add()
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, tel, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $this->db->prepare($sql)->execute($name, $tel, $email);
    }
    public function getAll()
    {
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users")->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

использовать так

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'root', '', [3 => 2]);
$user = new User($pdo);
$res = $user->getAll();
var_dump($res); //NULL
```

Comment: А чем плохо, что каждый класс отвечает за одно конкретное действие? Один - за подключение, другой - за инсерт, третий - за селект и т.д. Зачем надо один класс нагружать всеми этими функциями?

Comment: Ну ты почитай хотя бы что-нибудь про классы. что это такое и зачем они нужны. И чем отличаются от функций.

Comment: Хотя по сути ты прав - в данном случае надо не класс делать а просто нагородить кучу функций. это будет гораздо лучше отражать твою "архитектуру"

Comment: Ну, то есть аргументов у тебя нету, я понял ))

Comment: Ты такой милый в своем агрессивном невежестве:)

Comment: Ненуачо - на вопрос ты ответить не можешь, только пи$#ишь не по делу

Comment: @humster_spb, главная проблема твоей "архитектуры" - у каждого твоего класса собственное подключение к базе. Это неприемлемо. В варианте автора этого ответа - ты передаёшь в конструктор уже готовое подключение(только там typehint'а не хватает) + у тебя есть конкретная модель пользователя, которая отвечает за сущность пользователя. Я боюсь тут ещё чего писать, а то дядя Ипатьев заругает. =)

Comment: @vp_arth "у каждого твоего класса собственное подключение к базе. Это неприемлемо" - ну так а если каждый класс отвечает за одно конкретное действие по отношению к базе, как ему без своего подключения? конечно, если, как предлагает Ипатьев, создать один супер-класс и нагрузить его всеми возможными запросами к базе, тогда и подключение к него будет только одно. Но мне кажется, это плохой вариант - всё пихать в один класс. То же PDO отдельно предусматривает exec() и query(), как бы намекая нам, что это совершенно разные подходы к работе с базой, и разные классы должны за это отвечать

Comment: @humster_spb, По вашему есть только 2 крайности? либо один класс, либо миллион? Вы можете создать, например, по классу на таблицу, но они все будут использовать одно соединение, вы им его при создании дадите. Вообще, почитайте про ActiveRecord/DataMapper, незачем велосипеды изобретать.

Comment: Как интересно, должно быть, будет вам прочитать эти ваши идеи через пару лет)